# serializing sortables not working

Tags: jquery

I've tried everything and it still fails! What's wrong with this code?!?! I wanted to get the serialized sortable, it's that simple but I've looked on SO and found snippets.. applied with my code and it still doesn't work. It makes no sense at all. I did look at possible errors (and yes, there's set_number as specified by jQuery doc)... but still nothing works.

```
 <html>
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js'>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js">
    </script>
    <script>

$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();     
});

    $("form").submit(function(){         
    $('#thedata').val($( "#sortable" ).sortable("serialize"));
    return false;        
    });

    </script>
    <h1>
        Filters For Tables
    </h1>
    <h2>
        Filters for Assets
    </h2>
    <form action="validate.php" method="post">
        <input type='text' name='thedata' id='thedata' />
        <ul id="sortable">
            <li id="foo_0">ID</li>
            <li id="foo_1">TIME LOG</li>
            <li id="foo_2">DEVICE TYPE</li>
            <li id="foo_3">CHASSIS TYPE</li>
            <li id="foo_4">PARENT ID</li>
            <li id="foo_5">PARENT</li>              
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>
</body>

 </html>
```

Comment: so what exactly doesn't work - http://jsfiddle.net/LD5dZ/ ?

Comment: I also made a fiddle and works for me to. Are you sure the problem is this code?

Comment: @netrox in what way this doesnt work? what is failing? have you tried debugging to see where it blows up?

Comment: netrox, could you provide us more information? your choice of words "serialized sortable" is a little confusing here. Are you talking about the ID or the function?

Comment: Hi @netrox what browser are you using?

Comment: all modern brwosers - it is supposed to show the string of sortables inside the text box after you hit Update. It doesn't work at all.

Comment: it works fine in jsfiddle but not in IE, Chrome, FF.  Try copying the code and run it in a standalone browser.

Comment: netrox, if this is resolved please assign the bounty.

Comment: peter, I did. I clicked on +50. Doesn't that assign automatically to him? I see that I lost 50.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form element does not exist. You have to bind events when the DOM is ready. Just move this:

```
$("form").submit(function(){         
    $('#thedata').val($( "#sortable" ).sortable("serialize"));
    return false;        
});
```

To this function: $(function() {});
It works on JSFiddle because there is JavaScript called when the DOM is loaded I think.

Comment: Just spotted the same think, nice work @Drahomir. I think perhaps it works on js fiddle as it by default automatically wraps everything in document ready().

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be fine for me, when stripped away from the html.
http://jsfiddle.net/Zfu6N/

I've noticed you are not using a valid doctype e.g:

```
<!doctype html>
```

or e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

Which could be putting the browser into quirks mode.

It might be just because you're missing it in your example, but just in case.